# How to store data from JS input form into a text?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to store an input data from several fields into JS variables and then paste them in a text. Here is my code which doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

These are input fields:

```
    <ul id="listings">
            <li><input type="text" id="adjectives1" value="Adjective"></li>
            <li><input type="text" id="adjectives2" value="Adjective"></li>
            <li><input type="text" id="adjectives3" value="Adjective"></li>
    </ul>
```

And here is that text:

```
<div id="textualdiv"> As the <span id="adjective1">fatal</span> mating dance of a pair of black holes with a total mass of more than a billion suns. Mostly in the form of <span id="adjective2">violent</span> in space-time known as  <span id="adjective3">gravitational</span> waves.</div>

</div>
```

Here is JS script:

```
<script>
var adjective1 = document.getElementById("adjectives1").value;
var adjective2 = document.getElementById("adjectives2").value;
var adjective3 = document.getElementById("adjectives3").value;
</script>

<script>
document.getElementById('adjective1').innerHTML = adjective1;
document.getElementById('adjective2').innerHTML = adjective2;
document.getElementById('adjective3').innerHTML = adjective3;
</script>
```

It only pastes default "Adjective" values in the text which are already present in the input fields. But if I type something else it doesn't change the text, but keeps showing Adjective word.

Comment: You would need to listen for specific events such as *"change"* or *"keypress"* and update the HTML then. Your current code only updates the HTML once when it runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a change event handler, which will update the target element content on change of the input value.

```js
function update(el){
  var value = el.value;
  document.getElementById(el.id.replace('adjectives', 'adjective')).innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<ul id="listings">
  <li><input type="text" id="adjectives1" value="Adjective" onchange="update(this)"></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="adjectives2" value="Adjective" onchange="update(this)"></li>
  <li><input type="text" id="adjectives3" value="Adjective" onchange="update(this)"></li>
</ul>


<div id="textualdiv"> As the <span id="adjective1">fatal</span> mating dance of a pair of black holes with a total mass of more than a billion suns. Mostly in the form of <span id="adjective2">violent</span> <span id="noun3">ripples</span> in space-time known as  <span id="adjective3">gravitational</span> waves.</div>
```

Comment: It does seem to work, even though I don't understand what this "el" function is and how it works. I understood that I have to update my data once I fill in new text, but how this function works and what it does and how it works with "adjective" and "adjectives" without numbers on the end of them, I don't understand. But than you for help!

Comment: @NebularDust when the value of the input is changed it will call the `onchange` handler, which is calling the `update` function and is passing the changed input reference as its parameter... so `el` inside the `update` function is referring to the changed input element

Comment: @NebularDust To find the `span` to updated, first we are taking the `id` of the changed input element using `el.id`, so it will refer to a value like `adjectives1`, now using the `replace` function we are replacing `adjectives` with `adjective` so we will get `adjective1`

Answer (score 0):

you can hook an `onchange` event to the inputs so that when you change anything in the input, you change the `innerHTML` on the span tags.

```
<input type="text" id="adjectives1" value="Adjective" onchange="document.getElementById('adjective1').innerHTML = this.value;">
```